# Modeling a pair of dice using composition in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, random, dice

I've written a program all by myself, but I just want to make sure I did it right and if anybody has any suggestions on improving it in any way.

1. Define and implement the `Die` class depicted by the following UML diagram to create an ADT for one die (singular of dice) with faces showing values between 1 and the `numberOfFaces` on the die. Define a two-parameter constructor with defaults of 6 faces and 1 for face value. Define and implement a `roll()` method to simulate the rolling of the die by generating a random number between 1 and `numberOfFaces` and storing that number in `faceValue`. Provide an accessor to return the die’s face value and a `print()` method to print the die’s face value.
2. Use composition to design a `PairOfDice` class, composed of two six-sided `Die` objects. Create a driver program with a `main()` function to rolls a `PairDice` object 1000 times, counting then displaying the number of snake eyes (i.e. two ones) and box cars (i.e. two sixes) that occur.

**die.h**

```
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H

class die {

private:
    int numberOfFaces;
    int faceValue;
public:
    die();
    die(int, int);
    int roll();
    void print();
};
#endif
```

**die.cpp**

```
#include "die.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

die::die()
{
    numberOfFaces=6;
    faceValue=1;
}

die::die(int numOfFaces, int faceVal)
{
    numberOfFaces=numOfFaces;
    faceValue=faceVal;
}

int die::roll()
{
    faceValue=rand()%numberOfFaces;
    return faceValue;
}

void die::print()
{
    cout << faceValue << endl;
}
```

**pairOfDice.h**

```
#include "die.h"
#ifndef PAIROFDICE_H
#define PAIROFDICE_H

class pairOfDice :
    public die
{
private:
    die die1;
    die die2;
    int value1;
    int value2;
    int total;
public:
    pairOfDice();
    int roll();
};

#endif
```

**pairOfDice.cpp**

```
#include "pairOfDice.h"

pairOfDice::pairOfDice()
    :die(6,1)
{
    value1=1;
    value2=1;
    total=value1+value2;
}

int pairOfDice::roll()
{
    value1=die::roll();
    value2=die::roll();
    total=value1+value2;
    return total;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include"pairOfDice.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rolls=0, total=0, snakeEyes=0, boxCars=0;
    pairOfDice dice;

    while(rolls<1000)
    {
        total = dice.roll();

        if(total==2)
            snakeEyes++;
        else if(total==6)
            boxCars++;
        else
            rolls++;
    }

    cout << rolls << " " << snakeEyes << " " << boxCars << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `srand()`?

Comment: Prefer [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to `rand` when it is available.

Comment: @Jamal i was calling it in the roll method of the dice class but i moved it right before the loop in the main program and that seemed to fix the problem. idk if thats the best solution though ...

Answer (score 5):

Some miscellaneous remarks unrelated to object-oriented design:

- **Die face numbering:** Your die face values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  That's not how most people expect a six-sided die to be labeled.  It also makes an exceptionally weird definition of rolling snake eyes!
- **Biased die:** Since 6 is not a power of 2, if you just do `rand() % 6` then you have a [slightly biased die](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/1157100).
- **Roll miscount:** You aren't rolling a pair of dice 1000 times.  You're rolling a pair of dice until you get 1000 results other than 2 or 6.  You could probably have avoided this bug if you had used a for-loop instead of a while-loop, since for-loops impose a standard structure on your code.
- **Variable declaration:** In `main()`, the variable `total` is only used within the while-loop, so it should be declared at the point of use: `int total = dice.roll();`
- **Seeding:** You didn't actually call `srand()`.
- **Portability:** `system("pause")` is unportable.
- **ostream support:** Consider implementing `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, ...)` for printing.

Comment: Avoiding the roll miscount is a matter of putting `rolls++` on its own line, not part of the if statement.  It's not a matter of a for loop being better or worse than a while loop.

Comment: @MichaelShaw: In this context a for loop is better because it puts the loop invariants in one place where it's easy to see.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Of course you can fix the bug, but it would be better to address the root cause of the bug, so that you would be less likely to make such mistakes in the future.

Comment: @200_success: But the root cause of the bug was not lack of a for loop or presence of a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's not composition.  That was inheritance, done poorly.  The difference is, would you say that…

- A `pairOfDice` has two dice, but is not a die *(composition)*, or
- A `pairOfDice` is a loaded die *(inheritance)*?

Since you declared `pairOfDice` to publicly inherit from `die`, you are treating a `pairOfDice` as a dodecahedron that is somehow weighted to produce a random distribution biased towards 6 or 7.  I don't think you could produce such a physical object with just the right weight distribution.  It could exist in your imagination though.  Therefore, saying that `pairOfDice` *is* a `die` would be controversial modeling at best.

#### Composition

With composition, a `pairOfDice` contains two `die` members, but does not necessarily inherit from anything.

```
class pairOfDice {
private:
    die die1;
    die die2;
public:
    pairOfDice() {};
    int roll();
};

int pairOfDice::roll() {
    int value1 = die1.roll();
    int value2 = die2.roll();
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

That's all.  Note that you should not store `value1`, `value2`, or `total`.  All of that state is handled by the constituent `die1` and `die2` members.

#### Private Inheritance

C++ has a private inheritance feature, which could let you inherit the code for just one die, without letting anyone else know that you did so.

```
class pairOfDice : private die
{
private:
    die die2;
public:
    pairOfDice() {};
    int roll();
};

int pairOfDice::roll()
{
    int value2 = die2.roll();
    return ((die *)this)->roll() + value2;
}
```

The code above acts like the composition example.  Attempting to do `pairOfDice dice; die *diePtr = &dice;` would be a compilation error, since `pairOfDice` is not publicly a subclass of `die`.  Private inheritance is an odd feature, and you would be better off doing pure composition instead.

#### Public Inheritance

With public inheritance, you would be treating `pairOfDice` as a kind of `die` — a loaded 12-sided die.

```
class pairOfDice : public die
{
private:
    die die2;
public:
    pairOfDice() {};
    int roll();
};

int pairOfDice::roll()
{
    int value2 = die2.roll();
    return faceValue = ((die *)this)->roll() + value2;
}
```

Note that `pairOfDice` must now support every operation that `die` supports, including `print()`.  To ensure that `pairOfDice::print()` works, you must assign `faceValue` when rolling, and therefore the `faceValue` member of `die` must be changed from `private` to `protected` to support that.  That illustrates a kind of fragility that comes with sharing code through inheritance: the subclass might accidentally inherit code that doesn't work quite right, and in a sense the subclass is patching the superclass code.

The fragility of such an inheritance relationship is also a symptom of the fact that the inheritance was a long stretch of the imagination to start with (as discussed in the beginning of this review).  Let's just say, inheritance, whether of the public or private sort, is not really appropriate for this situation.

#### A better hierarchy

Perhaps it would be best to have a virtual base class representing number generators.

```
template <class T>
class randgen {
public:
    virtual T roll() = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class die : public randgen<int> {
    ...
};

class pairOfDice : public randgen<int> {
private:
    die die1;
    die die2;
public:
    ...
};
```

Everyone would agree that a `die` *is* a `randgen<int>` and that a `pairOfDice` also *is* a `randgen<int>`.  With a common base class, it would be possible to have a `randgen<int>*` pointer that points to either a `die` or a `pairOfDice`.  Finally, `pairOfDice` could be implemented using composition, which is the least error-prone way to reuse code.

Comment: Regarding *"Therefore, you would be better off using composition instead of inheritance as a code-reuse mechanism whenever possible"* - I'd say if you use inheritance for the sole purpose of code reuse your abstraction is broken

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, composition must be implemented in terms of members, not parents.

You could use default arguments and only have one constructor rather than two. It would make the code simpler.

The assignment also requested an accessor for face value. Make such side-effect free method `const`.

I suggest not putting `Die` and `PairOfDice` in the same class hierachy. The only interface they could possibly share is `roll()`, and that is only if the return type is void. Use class hierachies for things that are polymorphic, i.e. where you intend for instances of both classes to be used the same way in the same code.